# Exists a Way to Detect many WebCams in Java?

Tags: java, webcam

I'm trying to load many webcams at the same time to take pictures, but i cant, i was using the JMF but with this library I just can see *one* webcam, there is a way to switch between webcams, I'm trying to connect 10 webcams...

If there is no way to make this on Java, I appreciate any advice for another way to do that in another language.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Webcam Capture](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/) project. It supports many webcams by default. I was trying it with 3 webcams (2 x USB + 1 build-in) at once and it works pretty well.